# Fluent Groovy syntax using command chaining and maps

Tags: groovy, closures, fluent, method-chaining

Given the following Groovy code:

```
someMap = ['key':{ str -> println "SUCCESS: ${str}" }]
clos = { someMap }
```

All of the following are legal ways to print `SUCCESS: abc`:

```
clos(null)['key'] "abc"
clos null key "abc"
someMap['key'] "abc"
```

This one, however:

```
someMap key "abc"
```

throws a `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: key for class: ConsoleScript50`.

If `clos(null)` and `someMap` both resolve to `java.util.LinkedHashMap`, then what makes `clos null key "abc"` legal, but `someMap key "abc"` not legal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groovy understands `someMap key "abc"` as `someMap(key).getAbc()`, which won't work. You really need the dot:

```
someMap.key "abc"
```

Or square brackets

```
someMap['key'] "abc"
```

---

**Update**

> It seems that Groovy will always disambiguate a token like key as a call parameter (i.e. someMap(key)) if it can.

Yes, it will.

> Only if that interpretation doesn't make sense does it instead interpret the token as a property (.key) or map dereference (['key']).

No, Groovy will always understand the second parameter, without dots or parens, as a call parameter. This

```
function parameter
```

Is always undertood as

```
function(parameter)
```

It features no "precedence" over `object[key]`

If you keep adding stuff without dots or parenthesis to disambiguate, Groovy will keep adding parens and dots as per it's own rules. This:

```
gimme coffee with sugar and milk
```

Is understood as

```
gimme(coffee).with(sugar).and(milk)
```

Also this:

```
clos null key 'abc'
```

Will always be undertood as

```
clos(null).key('abc')
```

Comment: I'm new to Groovy, so please let me know if any of this is in error: It seems that Groovy will always disambiguate a token like `key` as a call parameter (i.e. `someMap(key)`) *if it can*. Only if that interpretation doesn't make sense does it instead interpret the token as a property (`.key`) or map dereference (`['key']`). In this case, `clos null key "abc"` works because `clos(null)(key)` wouldn't be valid syntax, so Groovy has no choice but to disambiguate it as `clos(null)['key']` instead. As you pointed out, `someMap(key)` is valid syntax, so it takes precedence over `someMap['key']`.

Answer (score 0):

because it translates to `someMap.key()...`, and there is no such method (only a property (via missing).  `someMap.key "abc"` also works.

the other call translates to `clos(null).key("abc")`, which first derefs into the map and then just calls `call` on the result.

```
def x = clos null key
assert x.is(someMap.key)
```